# How to transpose words, keeping the cursor at the same relative location to the word it moves?

Tags: text-editing

When transposing words, the cursor moves to the end of the word, how can the cursor be kept at the same location relative to the word?

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
(defun ideasman42-transpose-words (arg)
  (interactive "*p")
  (let ((chars-to-word-end
         (let ((point (point)))
           (if (or ; cases to behave like plain transpose-words.
                (looking-at "\\>") 
                (looking-at "\\(?:[ \t]*\n\\)*[ \t]*\\<") )
               0
             (save-excursion
               (forward-word)
               (- (point) point))))))
    (transpose-words arg)
    (backward-char chars-to-word-end)))
```

as a start?

Comment: I was hoping to avoid duplicating logic to delimit the word under the cursor, any mismatch in logic between this and forward-word's logic will cause bugs.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by getting the boundaries under the cursor from `thing-at-point`, then using them to set the cursor after transposing the word.

Unlike regular transpose-word.

- The cursor stays on the same character of the word.
- When there is no word to transpose with, the cursor doesn't move and a message is printed.

```el
(defun transpose-words--impl (arg)
  (let ((bounds (bounds-of-thing-at-point 'word)))
    (when bounds
      (let* ((pt-init (point))
             (pt-end-of-word (cdr bounds))
             (pt-offset (- pt-init pt-end-of-word))
             (pt-transpose
              (save-excursion
                ;; Without this, the first character will move the previous word.
                (goto-char pt-end-of-word)
                (if
                    (condition-case err
                        (progn
                          (transpose-words arg)
                          t)
                      (message err))
                    (+ (point) pt-offset)
                  nil))))

        (when pt-transpose
          (goto-char pt-transpose))))))

(defun transpose-words-backward ()
  (interactive)
  (transpose-words--impl -1))

(defun transpose-words-forward ()
  (interactive)
  (transpose-words--impl 1))
```

Use with evil mode for eg:

```lisp
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-M-l") 'transpose-words-forward)
(define-key evil-normal-state-map (kbd "C-M-h") 'transpose-words-backward)
```